# Cannot resolve symbol 'Id' for org.springframework.data.annotation.Id in IntelliJ

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I added a simple model for mongodb but IntelliJ is not able to resolve the annotation @Id. I tried invalidating caches but still it is not wokring.

[image]

here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
.....
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
.......
```

As you see in above pom.xml i have correct data dependencies for mongo. Am I still missing something?

Comment: did u try to reimport the pom dependancies?

Comment: @varman I tried reloading the project by 
1. Right click pom.xml  2. Maven --> Reload project

Comment: @Diwakar please share idea.log

Comment: Right click on middle of pom->maven -> Reimport. What is ur IDE suggesting

Comment: @Diwakar what about other annotations are they working?

Comment: @deadshot yes they are.

Answer (score 0):

You also need this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```